# Excel VLOOKUP for multiple items and combining them in one cell

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have an excel sheet like this:

| Phone Number | IMEI's |
| --- | --- |
| SIM 1 |  |
| SIM 2 |  |

I have another Sheet with same SIM's and IMEI numbers of phones in which these SIM's were. If SIM was in more than 1 IMEI i have it like this:

| Phone Number | IMEI's |
| --- | --- |
| SIM 1 | IMEI 1 |
| SIM 1 | IMEI 2 |
| SIM 1 | IMEI 3 |
| SIM 2 | IMEI 1 |

etc..
I need to use VLOOKUP or similiar code on the first sheet to show the IMEI numbers, but if the SIM was in more than 1 IMEI i need these IMEI's in same cell and separated by column. For example:

| Phone Number | IMEI's |
| --- | --- |
| SIM 1 | IMEI 1, IMEI 2, IMEI 3 |
| SIM 2 | IMEI 1 |

I tried simple VLOOKUP for the IMEI but it returns only first one it finds. I don't know how to use VBA. Thanks...

Comment: Use FILTER and TEXTJOIN

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know this it is new in Excel 365, it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

### Join Filtered Data

[image]

In `H2`:

```
=LET(Sims,A2:A21,Imeis,B2:B21,
    BYROW(G2:G6,LAMBDA(Sim,TEXTJOIN(", ",,UNIQUE(FILTER(Imeis,Sims=Sim))))))
```

In `D1` or `D9`:

(To get the SIMs sorted, in the last line you can use `SORT(HSTACK(upData,jData),1)`. To get the IMEIs sorted, you can similarly wrap a `SORT` around `FILTER`>)

```
=LET(Data,A1:B21,pCol,1,iCol,2,Delimiter,", ",
    uData,UNIQUE(DROP(Data,1)),pData,INDEX(uData,,pCol),
    upData,UNIQUE(pData),iData,INDEX(uData,,iCol),
    jData,BYROW(upData,LAMBDA(pRow,
        TEXTJOIN(Delimiter,,FILTER(iData,pData=pRow)))),
VSTACK(TAKE(Data,1),HSTACK(upData,jData)))
```

Practice `REDUCE` so you're ready when `BYROW`, `BYCOL`, `MAP`, and `SCAN` don't work.

```
=LET(Data,A1:B21,pCol,1,iCol,2,Delimiter,", ",
    uData,UNIQUE(DROP(Data,1)),pData,INDEX(uData,,pCol),
    upData,UNIQUE(pData),iData,INDEX(uData,,iCol),
    jData,DROP(REDUCE("",upData,LAMBDA(rRes,pRow,
        VSTACK(rRes,TEXTJOIN(Delimiter,,FILTER(iData,pData=pRow))))),1),
VSTACK(TAKE(Data,1),HSTACK(upData,jData)))
```